# Parse the CSV data which is available in single row

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below like data in dataframe. Note that - Contents is the only one column and this dataframe has only one record which has the data. In data, first row is header, lines are separated by LF.

How can I generate a new dataframe which will have 3 columns and corresponding data.

```
display(df)

Contents
============================
"DateNum","MonthNum","DayName"
"19910101","1","Tue"
"19910102","1","Wed"
"19910103","1","Thu"
```

Just for info, below is how the data looks

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split by new line to get an RDD[String], which can then be converted to a dataframe:

```
val df2 = spark.read.option("header",true).csv(df.rdd.flatMap(_.getString(0).split("\n")).toDS)

df2.show
+--------+--------+-------+
| DateNum|MonthNum|DayName|
+--------+--------+-------+
|19910101|       1|    Tue|
|19910102|       1|    Wed|
|19910103|       1|    Thu|
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Great, that worked! Could you explain in brief what .csv(....) part does exactly?

Comment: that part splits the string by newline and converts to a dataset of strings, each string representing a line in the content